# Turbulence in Spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, spacetime, turbulence

Is it possible for the phenomenon of turbulence – eddys and vortices on many scales – to occur in spacetime in the context of General Relativity? For example near a Kerr black hole.

If not, what is different about the governing equations of GR, vs those of fluid dynamics, that determines this?

Comment: *For example near a Kerr black hole.* The Kerr metric has no time-dependence at all (at least not in Boyer–Lindquist or Kerr–Schild coordinates).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turbulent spacetime from Einstein equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221432/)