# Reference for relativistic fluid dynamics

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations

I am looking for a book dedicated to relativistic fluid dynamics, for someone who has studied/studying *Fluid Dynamics* by Batchelor and *General Relativity* by Schutz. Schutz' book does include a minor chapter on ideal fluids, but it is very insufficient. I also had look at this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46584/), and I wonder if the books mentioned in that post are the only ones. Thanks for your suggestions.